# Import DB into Postgres running on Kubernetes

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes

I am running Ansible [AWX](https://github.com/ansible/awx) based on Docker compose setup, I need to upgrade the version of AWX which supports only Kubernetes.

I need to export the DB from the docker setup into Kubernetes but I don't know how to import the postgres dump into K8S. Can any one help me out please ?

Comment: In its current form, this question is probably too broad to answer. If you get postgres running in your Kubernetes environment and expose the port, you can just use the regular [dump and restore process](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/backup-dump.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can call pg_restore command directly in the pod specifying path to your local file as a dump source.

kubectl exec -i POD_NAME -- pg_restore -U USERNAME -C -d DATABASE < dump.sql

(or)

cat database.sql | kubectl exec -i [pod-name] --psql -U [postgres-user] -d [database-name]

Comment: Thanks a lot, is there a way to login to a pod docker and check what's inside same as we do with docker: docker exec -it <docker name> /bin/bash ?

Comment: You can attach to a running container almost the same way you do in docker - 
`kubectl exec -i -t <pod-name> -- /bin/bash`. If there is more than one container running you need to specify it with `--container` flag: `kubectl exec -i -t <pod-name> --container <app-name> -- /bin/bash`. If you are planning to run database in a pod, you may also want to look into [Persistent Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/)